# Find a set of (n) nodes where relationship weight between each pair of node is greater than a value(w)

Tags: neo4j

I have a database where each node is connected to all other nodes with a relationship, and each relationship has a weight. I need a query where given a weight w and a number of nodes n, I want all n nodes where each pair of relationship has a weight greater than w.

Any help on this would be great

Comment: how big is your graph ?

Comment: It has around 1500 nodes and each node shares a relation with every other

Comment: Are your weights directed? I.e. Are there two nodes N1 and N2 such that the weight from N1 --> N2 is different than the weight from N2 --> N1?

Comment: @RebeccaNelson - The weight between two nodes is same and is not dependent on the direction.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you would like your result set to look like. Something as simple as this query would return all paths that fall under your criteria:

```
MATCH p=()-[r:my_rel]->() WHERE r.weight > w RETURN p;
```

This would return all such paths.

If you would like the two nodes only (and not the entire pattern's results), you can return only those two nodes:

```
MATCH (n1)-[r:my_rel]->(n2) WHERE r.weight > w RETURN n1,n2;
```

Do note that due to Neo4J's storage internals, performing a search based on the properties of a relationship tends to not perform as well as those based on properties of a node.

Comment: For the downvote; is there something I can do to improve this answer?